# How to download a pdf file after filling a form

Tags: php

I would like people download an e-book but only after filling the form with the email. How to manage this issue? any suggestion?

---

ok sorry I'm going to be more precise. 
I have a form with an input email field  to be filled by the customer.

```html
<form id="contact" method="post" action="#">
      <div class="privacy"><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></div>
          <div class="input-email">
            <input type="text" placeholder="email@dominio.it" required class="box-email" name="email" style="border-color:#F03">
            <input type="submit" value="scarica l'ebook" class="btn btn-2 btn-2b" type='submit'>
                                      
            </div>
            <div class="caffe-fumoso"><img src="img/caffe+moka.png" alt="moka" / </div>
                         
         </form>
```

When an user presses the "send button" i want to things happen:
1) that i receive an email with the customer email ( i don't have implemented php database for now.. so i only will collect email users by email ) 2) begins the ebook download ( but i don't know how to do this )

OR

2) that i receive an email with the user email and that the user receives an email with the link to download the ebook. Is that possible with my code below?

```html
<?php

    $to = "info@mokagency.it";
    $from = $_REQUEST['email'];

    $fields = array();
    $fields{"email"} = "email";

    $body = "Ecco il messaggio inviato:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){   $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); }

    $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
 
 $mittente="info@mokagency.it";
$destinatario=$_POST["email"]. ', ';
$destinatario .= "info@mokagency.it";
$oggetto = "E-book Parliamo di Piccioli";
$corpo = "Buongiorno ,\n \n grazie per averci inviato la tua email. Ecco l'ebook <a href='(../img/piccioli.pdf)'>Parliamo di Piccioli</a>";    //    \n è l'andare a capo nel corpo della mail
mail($destinatario,$oggetto,$corpo,"From: $mittente\n\r"); 

mail($destinatario,$oggetto,$corpo,"From: $mittente\n\r"); 
?>
```

So if is well done i will receive an email with the user's info and the user receives an email with the link to download the ebook. I have tried it but until now i only receive the email user's info but nothing happen for the user

Thank you for any help

Comment: You could set a variable when the form is complete. Or have an ajax form with a callback function that provides the Web link when the PHP replies.

Comment: If you process the form at server side, what's wrong with a download response?

Comment: target an Iframe with the form and in the script for the iframe validate and store the email, if that passes do the download into the iframe, easy.

Comment: What have you tried? You haven't showed any attempt at solving your problem and have shared no code.

Comment: Please provide more info. You ask how to solve the issue yet present us with no issue to solve, only a description of what you want. Please make an edit to your question to explain **exactly** what it is you need solved. As it stands the question much too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague...

I am assuming your email form is one from your email service like constant contact or the like... You are going to have to return them to a download page...

if not

and the email is being processed on your server you are going to have to redirect them to the pdf from your grunt file...

You are new to this site... this site is designed to assist you with programming issues for things that you have already tried but isn't working where you provide your code for review and assistance... it is impossible to help you resolve your issue with such a vague question